# Как лучше переводить число в строку?

Tags: java

Программирую на Java, часто возникает задача переводить int/float/double в String. Часто я делаю например так

```
 ""+number
```

Просто потому что мне так удобнее, но мне почему-то кажется что не стоит так писать.

Знаю что можно делать например так

```
String.valueOf(number) 
Integer.toString(number) // для int
```

Какой способ будет правильнее использовать один из методов или можно писать `""+number`, и принципиально ли это вообще в этом случае?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Методы `String.valueOf` и `Integer.toString(int number)` одинаковы по эффективности, т.к. первый метод внутри себя вызывает второй.

По поводу `number+""` и `Integer.toString(int number)` несколько сложнее. Создание строки через `+""`, как правило, разворачивается компилятором в `StringBuilder`, с дальнейшим вызовом метода `append`. Согласно [моему тесту производительности](https://gist.github.com/izebit/8986f1ec4cebeeb1eedbbb7ed52be950), метод `Integer.toString` немного быстрее, процентов на 10-20.

Что происходит внутри метода `Integer.toString` ?

Если взглянуть на его реализацию, увидем, что там аллоцируется массив char, который заполняется числами, при помощи битовых сдвигов. В методе `StringBuilder.append(int number)` происходят аналогичные действия. Но, как мне кажется, за счет создания объекта `StringBuilder` этот способ оказывается медленнее.

Answer (score 1):

Основное различие данных методов в том, что если `number == null`, то:

- `String.valueOf(number)` **возвратит строку** `null`;
- при `Integer.toString(number)` **возникнет исключение** `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но хотелось бы услышать что-нибудь про  `""+number`

Comment: Это некрасиво, как минимум. Не делайте так.

Answer (score 1):

```
`String.valueOf()`
```

можно применять как к int,double, так и float - есть ли возникнет необходимость поменять тип данных переменной, не нужно будет править код с преобразованием.

Если вы посмотрите на реализацию для int метода `String.valueOf(int i)` - то метод вызывает `Integer.toString(i)` соответственно.

Последний вариант самый затратный и лучше избегать таких велосипедов.

Comment: последний это `""+number` ?

Comment: да, в этом случае просто создается StringBuilder, складывает пустую строку и число, как результат преобразовывает это в  String.